# Differentiable function plot looks non-differentiable in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm a student using "pgfplots" package first time and here is my code. It plots without problem, but it shows something unusual.

Though I plotted "7.06x/(x+53.37)" graph, differentiable, the plotted one looks like a non-differentiable function like the figure below.

Could you please give me some advise to solve it?

Thanks

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, 
    ymin=0,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    xlabel={$R_L \; (\Omega)$}, 
    ylabel={$V_L \; (V)$}, 
    legend style={at={(0.9,0.2)}, anchor=south east}]
\addplot[blue, only marks, mark=*, mark size=1.5pt] table {CC522_Exp1_3_data.txt};
\addplot [domain=1:10000, thick]{7.06*x/(x+53.3713)};
\legend{Measured data, $V_L=\frac{7.06R_L}{R_L+53.37}$}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: add `samples=301` or more until it looks smooth

Comment: Ah... It was really simple. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.